# Android Studio / Play store - Released Version compiled successfully but crashes

Tags: android, android-studio

I released an update of my app and encountered following problems:

The version I uploaded crashes because of a `ClassCastException`. Although when checking the code this can't be true.

**Observations**

- Android Studio compiled successfully => no problemss occurred
- PlayStore uploaded successfully => no problems occurred

The upload of the file is checked with a hash value of the apk isn't it? So this can't be the problem.

Can it be something in Android Studio? Is there some setting I can enable to check the release apk? To make sure nothing went wrong?

My solution was to recompile the app without any changes after a clean and it works again...

**Question**

- Can anyone explain how this can happen?
- Does anyone have tipps how I can avoid this? (besides always trying the release apk on my own phone... i must admit I don't do this, as I use my app in debug version permanently...)

Comment: where does ClassCastException() happen? It happens when you try to cast an object to one that's not compatible with. This happens in Runtime not Compile time. Please edit your question with the stack trace.

Comment: Recompiling the project solves the problem. Something went wrong while compilation or while uploading. The apk was executable but had some errors. I want to know where these errors can come from... As I said: recompiling WITHOUT any change to the code solves everything.

Comment: Try using report error when app crashes. You will be able to see the StackTrace of the app where the exception happened in your developer console :)

Comment: I know what the exception says. I know what line the error occurs. I know the app thinks the class is not the one it expects. The error occurs while inflating a view with only a button in it and casting it to a button. And the error says that it inflated a CheckedTextView. But it did not! While compiling the apk it probably got confused somehow and compiled something wrong. Again: recompile works!

Comment: My problem is that I did not get notified about the problems android studio had while compiling. I think the error in the apk comes from compiling as an error in uploading probably should fail due to hash check... and the resulting invalid apk would probably not work at all...

Comment: huh, that's so weird :o I've never had those type of problems..

Comment: Maybe even something in proguard failed. Still I would prefer a failure instead of an invalid apk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen from time to time when switching build types, or checking out a different branch of your repository if you don't clean your project.

My advice would be to always do a clean build when you perform either of these two actions, which will avoid the problem. It will not always be caught during an incremental compile because the cached code is still valid code (albeit with stale references).

Also, not testing your release version before publishing is a bad idea. Better to spend an hour making sure it works than release something that's no good for your users and could easily result in your app being uninstalled.

Comment: I'm jumping between two machines to develop... this makes sense to me. Can I somehow disable the increment build and force a clean for EVERY RELEASE build?

Comment: You could probably force it by making the `releaseCompile` task depend on the `clean` task, I don't know the way to do this off the top of my head but Google should turn something up. If I have answered your original question, please accept the answer :)